# Getting a relationship value from an Sobject

Tags: apex, soql

I need to get a relationship value from an sObject but I dont know how.

What I mean is the following.

I am doing a query and one of the fields I am getting is CreatedBy.Name. The query results are being stored in a SObject array because the query might be for a number of different objects.

The problem is I can't use

```
String name = (String) sObject.get('CreatedBy.Name')
```

So is there a way to do it that doesnt involve me getting the CreatedById and then querying for the name using that?